# Calculate yearly change of LST data from MODIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, raster-calculator, modis, land-surface-temperature

I have monthly raster scenes (June) from MODIS for the period 2000-2020. So for each year one scene.

Now I need to determine the yearly change in temperature for the month of June per pixel in degrees Celsius.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference using [Raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html?highlight=raster%20calculator#raster-calculator):

> The Raster Calculator in the Raster menu allows you to perform
> calculations on the basis of existing raster pixel values (see Fig.
> 16.20). The results are written to a new raster layer in a GDAL-supported format.